Green and Hankel Function
Hello I am trying to create a Greens function for the Laplacian and Helmholtz operator in dimensions larger than 3. Mathematica already has a Greens Function method programmed in but it has limitations i.e. can't produce the Greens functions for dimensions past 2 or 3. Here is a previous post of mine that explored this.
There is a formula on wikipedia, which references a paper, that provides the Greens function for the Helmholtz operator in any dimension. Using this formula, I made my own Greens function in Mathematica for any desired dimension. (Image of the formula is at the end of the question.)
n = 3;
p = (n - 2)/2;
c = 1/(2 I*(2 \[Pi] )^(p));
greenFn[r_, p_] = c*(k^p) HankelH1[p, k r]/(r^p);

Using n=3 and k=0 as a test case, this should produce the Greens function for the 3D Laplacian which is 1/(4pi r). However, I am getting 1/(2pi r). When increasing n the powers of r and pi are correct but the constants are off.
To analyze the case k=0, I had to use a limit since the Hankel function at 0 is complex infinity.
Limit[greenFn[r, p], k -> 0, Assumptions -> r > 0]

Here are my outputs for various n = 3, 4, 5, and 6
$-\frac{1}{2 \pi  r} $
$-\frac{1}{2 \pi ^2 r^2}$
$-\frac{1}{4 \pi ^2 r^3}$
$-\frac{1}{2 \pi ^3 r^4}$
The constants should be the surface area of a n-1 dimensional sphere.  One issue I can see Mathematica having is the evaluation of the limit. Can anyone see what I did wrong? I believe I have the formula correctly typed in. Thanks for any advice.

